# Can one precompile opencl kernels for devices s/he doesn't have?

Tags: c++, build, opencl

We are currently investigating switching from Cuda to openCL. I have pre-built the openCL kernels like you can in Cuda (using CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES). My quick question: is it possible to compile a byte code for a device you don't have (I install the AMD driver, for example, then compile for a set of Radeon cards, despite us only having NVIDIA cards in house?)

I know this would be torturous to maintain and is not suggested, I just want to know if it is currently even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK AMD does support this, but as an example, you can't install the Nvidia GPU driver (which provides their OpenCL support) without an Nvidia GPU.  Therefore, an Nvidia GPU is needed.  Honestly, this does not seem to be an intended use case.  Instead, loading and saving binaries is meant for caching a kernel so that it only gets compiled on the first time your app is run (and after any hardware changes or driver updates).